# In the manga Black god, do Kuro and Keita fall in love?

Tags: black-god

I've looked all over the place for this but I couldn't find anything on the manga just the anime version which was a little annoying after Kuro and Keita got so close. So yeah I was just wondering do they develop a relationship or are they forever just friends?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Kuro has a crush on Keita, proving so in Episode 22, though she never confessed how she felt to Keita* . in [Black God](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_God_(manga)#Main_characters) referred to Anime Version .

[This](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20130123155944AAAHsVa) and read [this](https://www.mangaupdates.com/showtopic.php?tid=12636) maybe you could find the answer , it has the discussion.(Anime)

In Anime : 
*No, they do not fall in love .*
 
In Manga :
*They do.*

Comment: if this is a little help .

Comment: I know you're not meant to put thanks in comments but thanks dude. I've been looking for ages. (I'm sorry for breaking any rules but I'm so grateful)